# Problem with a set without accumulation points

Tags: analysis

Let $S$ be a nonempty subset in $\mathbb R^m$ without accumulation points in $\mathbb R^m$. 
 Is then
$$
\inf \{ \|x-y\|: x,y \in S, x\neq y \} >0 \textrm{   ? }
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample : $A=\lbrace k; k+\frac{1}{k} | k\geq 1\rbrace$.

Comment: Thanks. What about the case $m=1$. This counterexample does not work in this  case?

Comment: @user111 I’ve rewritten it so that it works in any dimension.